# Smooth-Scroll not functioning properly

Tags: jquery, html, smooth-scrolling

I am working on a new page for our site and I have run into a small issue that I cannot figure out the solution to. We have a link in the top section of our site that we would like to, on click, have the page scroll down to the bottom of the page to the links to get started. The issue is that when clicked the page just jumps straight down with no animation. I found the code here http://jsfiddle.net/YtJcL/ and it works perfectly on the fiddle. Below is the code from my site. Any and all help is appreciated! Here is the actual page link: http://www.scrubsandbeyond.com/koibysanita.aspx

HEAD:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<a class="scroll" href="#destination1">apply now</a>

<section id="destination1">Let's get started!</section>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".scroll").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     //calculate destination place
     var dest=0;
     if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
          dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
     }else{
          dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
     }
     //go to destination
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');
 });
```

EDIT: added page link

Comment: I suggest posting more of your page code since what you are giving us is code taken from the Fiddle that already works. Second double check to make sure your jquery-1.9.1.min.js file is linked and working correctly.

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to add the link to the actual page that I am referring to! sorry about that...@crazymatt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is updated code from you site. Try this-

```
<script>
$(function(){
    function smoothScroll (duration) {
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {            

            var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

            if( target.length ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, duration);
            }
        });
    }
    smoothScroll(400);    
});

</script>
```

Comment: It did not fix the issue, but I am unsure what the issue is exactly. The jquery works on the page, because the parallax scrolling working in the blue section. @RJ

Comment: @idontwantnoscrubs : I've updated my code. Please use that. Only update the script tag where you wrote `smoothScroll ` code. Issue is because of the code was not wrapped inside the jquery `doument.ready` funciton that cause code to run before DOM loading complete. I've used the short form of `document.ready`.

Comment: I am trying to make it just stop a bit earlier, maybe at the beginning of the green section. is there an easy way to accomplish this? thank you for your help!! @RJ

Comment: @idontwantnoscrubs : Glad it works! Just change the code line from `scrollTop: target.offset().top` to `scrollTop: target.offset().top-60`  Where `60` can be any amount of space you want to stop before, change it accordingly as you like.

Comment: Perfect thanks! I actually just ended up placing the section tag around the bottom green section and it worked out perfectly @RJ

Answer (score 0):

I think a similar but efficient jQuery implementation would be this-

```
function smoothScroll (duration) {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

        var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

        if( target.length ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, duration);
        }
    });
}
smoothScroll(400);
```

Comment: It may or may not work, it still just jumps down to the anchor with no animation.@PratinavBagla

Comment: @idontwantnoscrubs I think It might be a problem with the jQuery loading or some other issue other than the script. You should check all the scripts if they are loading or not. Also make sure that the jQuery loads before your script.

Comment: i have other jQuery on the page that works just fine, which is why I'm so confused. it does seem like the jquery is not working based on what is going on, but on the same page there is a parallax scrolling feature which is also jquery.